# Issues while using related names

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is the Course and LearnerCourse model:

```
class Course(BaseModel, Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    name = models.TextField(_("Course Name"), max_length=100,
                            blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField(
        _("Course Description"), blank=True, null=True)
    course_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)....

class LearnerCourse(BaseModel, Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, verbose_name=_("Course"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True, related_name='course_learner_courses')
    learner = models.ForeignKey(Learner, verbose_name=_("Learner Course"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    course_subscription = models.ForeignKey(CourseSubscription, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    enroll_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Course Enroll Date"))
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

in LearnerCourse used the related name for the course field, after that
When used like this

```
    details = LearnerCourse.objects.filter(learner=learner_id).all().order_by('-datetime_created')    
    print("details", details)   
    courses = details.course_learner_courses.all()  
    print("courses", courses)
```

which causes an error 'SafeDeleteQueryset' object has no attribute 'course_learner_courses'
Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the `details` queryset to access each individual `LearnerCourse` instance and then retrieve the related courses. Here is updated code:

```
details = LearnerCourse.objects.filter(learner=learner_id).all().order_by('-datetime_created')    

# Iterate through each LearnerCourse instance in the queryset
for learner_course in details:
    courses = learner_course.course_learner_courses.all()  
    print("courses for LearnerCourse ID {}: {}".format(learner_course.id, courses))
```

From this above code, we iterate through each `LearnerCourse` instance in the `details` queryset and then access the related courses using `learner_course.course_learner_courses.all()`. This should resolve the issue which you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
details = LearnerCourse.objects.filter(learner=learner_id).all().order_by('-datetime_created')  

#it is query set not object so you have loop the details to get object 

course_list = []
for detail in details:
    courses = detail.course_learner_courses.all()
    course_list.append(courses)

print(set(course_list))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).